# Missed predefined variables in HTTP Authentification

Tags: php, http-authentication

I'm facing something weird, after move one of my application to different server/host provider(from centOS to Ubuntu Server). So basicly, i have simple http authentification as auth module in that app. It uses predefined value, in environment variables, which is : `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`. As you can see on my title, for somehow reason, these predefined value which i used in my auth module, is missing!

I check my environment setting, in my php.ini, since by these link : http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php
mention that In safe mode, the variables PHP_AUTH_USER, PHP_AUTH_PW, and AUTH_TYPE are not available. I try set it on/off without different result. And `REMOTE_USER` var is not available too in my case.

Someone ever face something like these? Any suggestion?

Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Did you restart your server after changing the php.ini?

Comment: Have you enabled Basic Authentication in an Apache config (httpd.conf, vhost, .htaccess, etc)? You won't see those until the client has authenticated

Comment: @Phil, the HTTP authentification box was popped out. The only problem is, those `PHP_AUTH` variable, is not set after user authenticated (fill in username and password).

Comment: Did you look at the headers that client sends to server(with firebug/tcpdump or something)? Is there "Authorization" header? Please post the headers that you send to client. And what web server are you using? I remember there were some problems with IIS.

Comment: The Authorization header was sent properly along side with other HTTP Request header. I can see them by using Fiddler, my web debugger. The problem is, in my previous hosting/environment, `PHP_AUTH` is set, and i use both `PHP_AUTH_USER` and `PHP_AUTH_PW` to authenticate the user, but in my new hosting, `PHP_AUTH` variable is not set or/and not available.

Comment: What web server are you using? If you are using Apache how is your PHP installed(Apache module or cgi)? If it is Apache module then you should be able to do "print_r(apache_request_headers());" and see all HTTP headers there("Authorization" header too). In case of cgi you may have to do some hacks like: http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/http-auth-php-cgi.html (You should find some more up-to-date article).

Comment: `In case of cgi you may have to do some hacks like: besthostratings.com/articles/http-auth-php-cgi.html` @XzKto, Thanks for give the right direction. That was obvious, my PHP is run as CGI in these new host. I felt very stupid right now, since these thing completely didnt checked by me at the first time.

Comment: @toopay: I'm glad I could help, but your last post was really painful to read: "The English language is dead at your feet, blood leaking from the chainsaw wounds in its chest as you ejaculate over its mangled corpse." :(

Comment: `The English language is dead at your feet, blood leaking from the chainsaw wounds in its chest as you ejaculate over its mangled corpse.` lol Well, i can't agree more with that. Sorry for that, to all. My english indeed terrible (but i will not stop to learn).

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem. Have a look at

https://github.com/cweiske/SemanticScuttle/blob/master/www/api/httpauth.inc.php

for an example how to fix the problem.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` var is not available too in my case. If it exist, of course we can explode and decode both username and password  using `base64_decode()`, but its just not there. The HTTP authentification box was poped out, but after fill username & password, its all not set/NULL.